# Using setwd() to return to default in R

Tags: r

Does anyone know of a simple way to return to the default working directory in R?

I know I can just type in my home path...

```
setwd("C:/Users/me/Desktop")
```

...but I guess I'm lazy. Is there a default command or something such as...

```
setwd(default)?
```

Thanks if you know the answer to this.

Paul

Comment: There's no such thing as a "default working directory in R".  The working directory is determined at startup and can vary based on several things.

Comment: Just create a variable in your .Rprofile like: `myoriginalwd <- getwd()`.

Comment: @Thomas: that still will vary based on how R is invoked, which doesn't seem to be what the OP wants.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Ah, I suppose, I was thinking of "default" as session-specific, but you're probably right that that's not the intention.

Comment: My answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66962964/5114585 & my quick video at https://youtu.be/hMjzO4bAi70 will help you set a permanent working directory [when not in projects]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution, since the `Defaults` package has been archived:

```
# Use `formals<-`, but note the comment in the examples of ?formals:
#
## You can overwrite the formal arguments of a function (though this is
## advanced, dangerous coding).
formals(setwd) <- alist(dir = "C:/Users/me/Desktop")
```

Or you could mask `base::setwd()` with something like:

```
setwd <- function(dir) {
  if (missing(dir) || is.null(dir) || dir == "") {
    dir <- "C:/Users/me/Desktop"
  }
  base::setwd(dir)
}
```

---

UPDATE: The Defaults package has been archived, so this solution only works if you download the package from the CRAN archive and build from source yourself.

You could use the [Defaults](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Defaults/) package to set it to what you want.  Then you could just call `setwd()`.

```
library(Defaults)
setDefaults(setwd, dir="C:/Users/me/Desktop")
setwd()
```

See [this answer if you want to put the above code in your .Rprofile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4996252/271616).

Comment: If I try to install the package I get this: Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Defaults’ is not available (for R version 3.3.3). Looking it on google I found out that Package ‘Defaults’ was removed from the CRAN repository.

Answer (score 1):

when you log in to R, type getwd(), that is your default working directory

Comment: Only for that specific instance of R. It can be different in other instances. I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Answer (score -2):

use (PWD) in the termial ,hope you got what you want

Comment: ...and what if they're using Windows?

Comment: there is no termial in windows

Comment: true but it's work defferant way than the terminal in the linux unbuntu

Comment: Yep, just like bash is different than sh.

Comment: Wot? Yous Windows guys don't all have cygwin installed? :-0