# Set R 3.5.1 working directory permanently

Tags: r

I am having trouble setting my working directory permanently, recently updated to R 3.5.1, using windows 10.

I have tried both suggestions here - [Cannot permanently Change R Working Directory - Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51093818/cannot-permanently-change-r-working-directory-windows-10)

but neither work. Setting the directory in the "start in" in shortcut properties has always usually worked

Thanks

Comment: I very strongly suggest using the Projects feature in RStudio: https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-gapminder/02-project-intro/ It would sidestep your issue altogether.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added, I'm using base R, not studio

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use an IDE?

Comment: See this https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/3-3-r-startup.html#r-startup

Comment: Thanks @Tung! That worked!

Comment: My answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66962964/5114585 & my quick video athttps://youtu.be/hMjzO4bAi70 will help you set a permanent working directory [when not in projects]